# Unable to perform getobject from aws s3 in aws-lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to aws-lambda and aws-s3. I am trying to create one microservice using api-gateway, aws s3 and aws lambda.
I have written lambda function to retrive object from s3, but it sends null and not throwing any error. I am not sure what is going wrong.
I have setup role and gave access to s3 and used that role for lambda

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var params = {
      "Bucket": "bucketname",
      "Key": "keyname"
        };

    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
      if(err) {
          return "error while fetching data";
      } else {
          return data;
      }

    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should try adding some debug statements in there that will help you understand where it breaks. Is it actually failing to get the file from S3 or is it failing to respond or something in between?

Comment: This is not a good way to return the contents of a file. API Gateway has a payload size limit of 10MB, for one thing. You're also proxying file downloads which is not ideal. A better solution is to return a pre-signed URL to the client and then let the client fetch the object directly from S3.

Comment: As to the problem in your code, your 'return data' statement is not doing what you think it's doing (it's not returning from the exported handler function). That return statement is within the scope of the getObject callback function and hence it is returning from within that scope. This is basic JavaScript async callback behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the data in the proper response format required for API gateway proxy and use the callback parameter to reply, so change your function to look like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        "Bucket": "bucketname",
        "Key": "keyname"
    };

    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            return callback(new Error("error while fetching data"));
        } else {
            let response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {
                    "x-custom-header" : "my custom header value"
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            };
            return callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};
```

If you're not using API gateway proxy Lambda integration, then you can simply change the response to just `return callback(null, data);`